# How do I register .ocx files in VB6?

Tags: vb6, ocx

I want to be able to install the application I built using VB6.0 on an end user machine without having to install the VB6.0 program. Some say the .ocx files need to be registered. If so, how do Iregister those files?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run regsv32.exe  on target machine.

Comment: regsvr32 is used for registering ActiveX controls

Comment: thank u all for the contribution so far. that has solved the problem. am grateful enof.